# Validar si el usuario corresponde al administrador y cuando no

Tags: html, jsp

¿Cómo validar si el usuario de mi consulta en servlet corresponde al administrador y cuándo no?

Aqui mi código:

```
String usuario = request.getParameter("usuario");
        String contraseÃ±a = request.getParameter("pass");

        Consultas co = new Consultas();

        if (co.autenticacion(usuario, contraseÃ±a)){
          HttpSession objsesion = request.getSession(true);
          objsesion.setAttribute("usuario", usuario);          
          objsesion.setAttribute("pass", contraseÃ±a);
          response.sendRedirect("menu.jsp");
        }
          else if (co.autenticacion(usuario="vandaner" , contraseÃ±a)){
          HttpSession objsesion = request.getSession(true);
          objsesion.setAttribute("usuario", usuario);
          response.sendRedirect("jefe.jsp");
        }
        else {
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Ya lo tienes hecho no? Entiendo que el admin es "vandaner". Explica cuál es el problema. Eso sí, dale la vuelta a los `if`. Pon primero el del admin, y en caso de que no sea compruebas el de usuarios. Ya que el admin también es un usuario.

Comment: mi problema es que cuando en mi formulario de inicio de sesion yo ingreso mi administrador me manda a la pagina de cualquier usuario y no a la del administrador ese es el problema

Comment: El administrador con el que estás intentando entrar es `vandaner` no?

Comment: si ese es mi administrador

Answer (score 0):

Comprueba primero al administrador, después el resto de usuarios.

En tu código, primero compruebas TODOS los usuarios, en los cuales está tu administrador, y loguea como usuario. Nunca llega a preguntar en `else if`.

```
 String usuario = request.getParameter("usuario");
 String contraseÃ±a = request.getParameter("pass");

     Consultas co = new Consultas();

            if (usuario=="vandaner"){
              if (co.autenticacion(usuario , contraseÃ±a)){
                HttpSession objsesion = request.getSession(true);
                objsesion.setAttribute("usuario", usuario);
                objsesion.setAttribute("pass", contraseÃ±a);
                response.sendRedirect("jefe.jsp");
              }
            }
            else if (co.autenticacion(usuario, contraseÃ±a)){
              HttpSession objsesion = request.getSession(true);
              objsesion.setAttribute("usuario", usuario);          
              objsesion.setAttribute("pass", contraseÃ±a);
              response.sendRedirect("menu.jsp");
            }

            else {
                response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
            }

        }
```

Comment: y como hago eso? soy nuevo en esto del desarrollo con JSP y la verdad es lo unico que me falta

Comment: Ahí tienes el código @DanHermesReyesOsnaya Fíjate que es lo mismo que el tuyo pero al revés.

Comment: a cierto, pero ya lo habia puesto asi y tampoco funcionaba :'(

Comment: Qué ocurre con el código así?

Comment: me pasa lo mismo que cuando lo tenia abajo en el else if

Comment: Edito la respuesta, prueba ahora.

Comment: de hecho asi como me lo mandaste lo tenia al principio y en mi inicio de sesion cuando introduzco el usuario administrador si me lo detecta pero cuando ingreso otro usuario x me deja ahi mismo en el formulario

Comment: Prueba ahora. Si poniéndolo a la inversa te estaba metiendo en `menu.jsp`, introduciendo como usuario `vandaner` tiene que llevarte a `jefe.jsp`. El código en ambos `if` es el mismo, lo único que cambia es el nombre del usuario.

Comment: me mando error :(